# What is this fluorinated organic substance?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure, molecules, amines, identification

The corresponding author of the paper where this formula was published as appendix passed away. Can someone help me with identifying what is the name of this compound and why have strange zig-zag between Nitrogens

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is generally known as Selectfluor, a source of electrophilic fluorine. The zig-zag line is a 2-D representation of the third ethylene $\ce{-CH2-CH_{2} -}$ unit that links the two nitrogens. [more here](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/technical-documents/articles/chemfiles/selectfluor.html) and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selectfluor)

Comment: thank you very much. do you know if there is other way to donate F?

Comment: Yes, there are several other sources of electrophilic fluorine. This Wikipedia article is a good starting point  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrophilic_fluorination

Answer (score 21):

The name of the compound is 1-chloromethyl-4-fluoro-1,4-diazoniabicyclo[2.2.2]octane bis(tetrafluoroborate) (CAS #: 140681-55-6), which is commonly known as *Selectfluor*, a trademark of Air Products and Chemicals (see Waylander's comment elsewhere). Different view of the compound is given below (to you to understand the zig-zag feature):

[image: selectfluor]

Introduced in 1992, this organic salt is used as a fluorine donor in organic synthesis (Ref.1). For example of using *Selectfluor* as a source of fluorine, see Ref.2:

[image: Selectfluor as a source of fluorine]

**References:**

1. R. Eric Banks, Suad N. Mohialdin-Khaffaf, G. Sankar Lal, Iqbal Sharif, Robert G. Syvret, "1-Alkyl-4-fluoro-1,4-diazoniabicyclo[2.2.2]octane salts: a novel family of electrophilic fluorinating agents," *J. the Chem. Soc., Chem. Commun.* **1992**, *(8)*, 595-596 (DOI: 10.1039/C39920000595).
2. Timothy J. Barker, Dale L. Boger, "$\ce{Fe(III)}$/$\ce{NaBH4}$-Mediated Free Radical Hydrofluorination of Unactivated Alkenes," *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **2012**, *134(33)*, 13588-13591 (https://doi.org/10.1021/ja3063716).

Comment: is this substance toxic to cells or not environmentally friendly?

Comment: *Not related to the question* Which application do you use for these figures? Is there an open-source alternative (if the one you're using is proprietary)?

Comment: @SSimon yes Selectfluor is a toxic substance. PPE is very necessary when handling it.

Comment: @Waylander thank you. Is there any substance that can give F ions but that is not toxic?

Comment: @SSimon - there are many compounds that can give an "F ion" -- i.e., fluoride. For example, NaF gives F ions when dissolved in water. It is sufficiently nontoxic that it is added to toothpaste and drinking water. However, the point of Selectfluor is that is does not donate an ion; it donates a neutral F which forms a covalent bond with the target.  Any compound that can perform this function on a wide variety of organic compounds must be toxic.  Why? Because people are made out of a wide variety of organic compounds, and we do not want to be fluorinated.